# Is there a resource that links legal terminology to categories of law?

Tags: legal

By categories, I mean areas such as:

```
Bankruptcy law
Consumer finance
Contracts
Tax law
Employment Law
Housing discrimination
```

I’m looking to build a list of specific terminology by legal category, and am wondering if this already exists somewhere.

For example: “Chapter 11,” “Bankruptcy petition,” “Adversary proceeding,” all relate to Bankruptcy law.

The two parts I'm looking to join together do exist, on sites such as https://dictionary.law.com/Default.aspx and https://www.enjuris.com/students/types-of-law-careers.html, but it's the connection between them that's proving difficult.

Does anyone know if a resource like this already exists?